# What is the oldest "commercial logo" known?

Tags: economy, trade

I'm writing a paper on logos, iconography and different forms of identifications for trade activities. The paper starts with history of logos, which is pretty easy and known. However, I'm wondering: which is the oldest "brand logotype" ever?

To define a brand logotype, I use the following characteristics:

- It needs to have a name
- Preferably, it should have a purpose
  (activity) and/or icon or symbol
- It needs to be strictly related to
  trading or any economic PRIVATE activity

So, for example, a brand logotype is NOT an Egyptian Cartouche or the Ichthys, because they don't represent a commercial activity or brand.

So far, the oldest I could find is a bronze plate from Song Dinasty for *Liu's Needle Shop* , which is part of an advertisement commonly accepted as the oldest advertisement ever (just not necessarily the oldest BRAND). However, I'm not sure that's correct. I have seen advertisements in Pompeii, Herculanus and Ostia (sadly, I don't remember if there was a brand *per se*, the closest I can remember is a tavern in Ostia Antica that had some kind of sign at the entrance, which could have been merely decorative). And it seems to me ancient Egyptian, Roman or even Greek traders needed some kind of *brand identification*.

Anyways... is **Liu's Needle Shop** the oldest brand ever or is there an older one?

Comment: You should probably try to come up with a more narrow definition. That [Song dynasty advertisement](https://depts.washington.edu/chinaciv/graph/bunny.jpg) is not a very impressive logo. There are manufacturer marks on e.g. swords and marks on building materials (including in the pyramids I believe) which may fit your current definition, and are pretty old.

Comment: The [Dutch East India Company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_East_India_Company)'s logo was possibly the first globally recognized corporate logo. ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logo))

Comment: @TomasBy I understand old representations and iconography might not be very impressive, but Liu's is the one commonly accepted as first advertisement. The swords would be very interesting, but the pyramids are not an example, because as I said in my *pretty narrow* definition, the builder's name is not a commercial brand. The Dutch East example is great. Technically, the oldest *modern* logo is Stella Artois which is 300 years older, but there are no depictions of the original logo, so this one is a great find, thank you!

Comment: Here is a relevant article. https://time.com/2904290/10-oldest-company-logos/

Comment: Well, they are (I think) symbols, not names, but we probably don't know very well what they mean, so it may or may not be relevant.

Comment: What is a "*commercial enterprise*"? Medieval guilds 9with their distinctive *hallmarks*) were profit-seeking organizations. So were the Hanseatic League; the Republic of Venice (employing the [*Banner of St. Mark*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_the_Republic_of_Venice) since 697 as well as all its leading families with their own ensigns and coats-of-arms; What about the distinctive banding of [*Damascus Steel*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damascus_steel#History)? it seems to me the question is not who was first, but how far back one cares, or is able, to look.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens it rules out national and religious symbols? Banners and coats-of-arms seem to be more like the opposite of a logo.

Comment: @Spencer yes, I know that article. In fact, it's a reproduction of another article but some of its data is incorrect. An example: the above mentioned Stella Artois logo didn't exist until XX century, but they say they used in XIV century (they used another for "Der Hurm", not for Stella Artois.) As a matter of fact, the Stella word is from XX century as well

Comment: @PieterGeerkens, these were military or guvernmental organizations, not brands. I took a look to Damascus Steel, but the article doesn't mention a brand or even a logo, just a type of craftmanship

Comment: bah, I see it was closed. OK, thank you to those that tried to help.